# Road Type Symbology Query (non technical)

Tags: symbology, road

Does anyone know of a good resource/resources for road type symbologies?

I am looking to update the symbology of a Road class layer which has 8 categories. The Road schedule is for Ireland. So a standardised symbology for the EU/EU country would be ideal. I know road types would differ in differ countries but some ideas would be great!

I am currently using symbology from Ordnance Survey Ireland by as you can see the Local Primary-Tertiary symbologies are pretty much indistinguishable.

[image]

Comment: For the EU you would need more categories, autobahn, toll road,route nationale etc https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchy_of_roads  and what about the Swiss? see http://www.viamichelin.com/web/Maps Europe on how they classify the roads

Comment: This might help from OpenStreetMap Wiki http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Highway:International_equivalence

Comment: Don't forget that symbologies often (usually/always?) change (often radically) for different scales of map, even for one country and one company.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [the INSPIRE data specification for transport networks in Europe](http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/documents/Data_Specifications/INSPIRE_DataSpecification_TN_v3.1.pdf). It is not a very appealing document, but it may give some insight.

- Chapter 5.3, see especially the enumerations and code lists in 5.3.2.2
- Chapter 11 describes some styles based on these classifications

Comment: Thanks Julien for identifying the specific sections of that daunting doc!